# How to find out that someone is using a Keylogger on the machine I am using?

Tags: security, malware

HW/SW/whatever keyloggers are there. How to find out? E.x.: Regularly check the cable of the keyboard, because there could be HW keyloggers:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgfbY.jpg

But what about other HW keyloggers, or Software keyloggers? [Using a Linux, e.x.: Fedora or Ubuntu for OS!] - How to track keylogger softwares/solutions? What are the "best-practises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system has been compromised at the root level, then the attacker can hide a keylogger from anything you try to detect it - by linking in a custom kernel module that intercepts the system calls that might lead to its detection at the kernel level.

If that's what you suspect has happened, your only way to be reasonably sure you'll find it is by booting from a known safe live-CD image and manually scan for anything suspicious or out of place. Software like chkrootkit and debsums (the latter only applicable for debian-based distros, obviously) will help.

Comment: that's ok, but I was thinking of soultion like are there any system calls that can be submerged - that something is catching the keypresses?

Comment: If your system is compromised at the root level then the hacker can already "submerge" those system calls and nothing at the console level would even be able to notice.

Comment: @lancebaynes The essential problem is that at that point you're basically asking the kernel "are you lying to me?", and I'm not sure why you'd expect the answer to be other than 'yes'...